# Search Between Two Dates using VB NET, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

I'm doing a search between two dates but it appears all dates, I only wanted is appear determinated dates for example "July" but it appears all twice.

[image: Search of Two Dates]

This is the VB Code I'm using

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Gd_perfil()

Dim sql As String

Dim Fecha_Inicial As String
Dim Fecha_Final As String


Fecha_Inicial = DateTimePicker1.Value
Fecha_Final = DateTimePicker2.Value


sql = "Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE " & _
    "Fecha_Ingreso Between " & _
        "# " + Fecha_Inicial + " # And # " + Fecha_Final + " #"


GridView1.BestFitColumns()


End Sub
```

I have a question about the other code that shows the table, that selection table does not affect the code?

```
Public Sub Gd_perfil()
Dim dt As DataTable
vm_sql = "Select id,Modulo,Usuario,Fecha_Ingreso,Observaciones FROM KNTB_Bitacora "
sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)
GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla

GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub
```

Because in that code when this starts at the time of search, several dates appear  but it does not appear only a Date of Month.

Comment: Dates are not strings. You are converting a datetime value to a string then you are hoping the database understands your converted value to a date. Learn how to use a parameterized query

Comment: Before you write anymore code you need to learn about, understand and start using parameterized queries. The pattern you have is vulnerable to sql injection as well as misinterpretation of values.

Comment: If you stored your dates as strings, you have a problem you need to correct ASAP. Your `Gd_perfil()` doesn't filter by Date, it loads all records. The `sql` where there's a filter by date is in the middle of nowhere. To filter by date, you need to have `DateTime` fields and provide `DateTime` values to the filter. If you need to format your Dates in non-US format, use the `Format` property of the corresponding DataGrid(?) columns. Use parameters ([Parameters.Add()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add)) to specify the filter values.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm using the International Format to compare the code execution

Comment: @Jimi Do I remplace Gd (GridView) to Format?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What I meant is that all existing DataGrids' (I don't know which one you're using but it's the same for all) Columns have a `Format` property that allows to present the data in a specific way. Date and Time often need to be presented localized (formatted using the local/current Culture rules). What matters is that you store Dates and Times as `DateTime` fields, not strings. Also, use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) in your queries, do not (ever) concatenate strings.

Comment: So do I change String to Parameters?

Comment: What is Button1_Click attempting to do? You construct an Sql query but you don't actually execute it or assign its result to the GridControl. If you've already loaded the GridControl with the contents of the KNTB_Bitacora then you need to either execute the query again and re-bind the grid or use the GridControl's built-in filtering mechanisms to hide the rows that don't meet your date range.

Comment: `Button1_Click` is the Search Button, This action is for search of Two Dates, `DateTimePicker1` and `DateTimePicker2` the `Gd_Perfil` is to show the table

Comment: My point above is that you are never executing the Sql statement with the date parameters. You only ever populate the GridControl with the full table data.

Comment: Hi, I just modified the code, but it gives me error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value` but I'm gonna post it again